# How do I restore the Windows XP Welcome Screen?

Tags: windows-xp, login

The default Windows XP logon screen seems to no longer be functioning. I'm presented with a logon box asking for my username and password - I can still log in, but I wish to restore the old method.

I've tried the following:

- Toggled *Welcome Screen* and *Fast User Switching* in Control Panel, it had no effect.
- Ran `control userpasswords2` and toggled both *Users must enter ...* and *Require users to press ...*
- Ran system file checker: `sfc /scannow`, there were no problems.
- Verified the *Fast User Switching Compatibility* service is up and running (`services.msc`).
- Checked the *Terminal Services* service for good measure.
- Checked the *Event Viewer* for relevant issues, there were none.
- Verified there's no *GinaDLL* entry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`.
- Verified `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\LogonType` is set to 1.
- Verified `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\Winlogon\AllowMultipleTSSessions` is set to 1.
- Imported the [Restore Fast User Switching](http://web.archive.org/web/20110114054028/http://www.kellys-korner-xp.com/regs_edits/fus.reg) registry file from *kellys-korner-xp.com* (which includes *AllowMultipleTSSessions* as above).
- Checked if `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system` was possibly overriding the above.
- Ran [XP_FixLogon.exe](http://web.archive.org/web/20110125011019/http://dougknox.com/xp/scripts_desc/fix_xp_logon.htm) from *dougknox.com* to verify the default standard Gina was in use.
- Getting desperate: double checked stats of gina files: `dir *gina* /p/s/a` (even after SFC verified them).
- Getting desperate: used [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/)'s [RegScanner](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html) to search for strings containing gina in the registry looking for something suspicious.

Comment: Did you try pushing `CTRL + ALT + DEL` twice?

Comment: @todda Actually yes. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After scouring the web and all of the above failed, I tried [Logon Loader Recovery Tool 1.0](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Back-Up-and-Recovery/Logon-Loader-Recovery-Tool.shtml) (link to softpedia as it's no longer hosted on author's website) from [Daniel Milner](http://www.milnersolutions.com/).

Success! The author has informed me his tool sets the following registry value:
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\UIHost` to `logonui.exe`

Comment: +1 for posting the solution here as this may be helpful to others.